# Android not detecting intent action correctly

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, action, outgoing-call

I am writing an Android app (kotlin) which logs incoming and outgoing calls (information about phone number and date). So far, I can obtain phone number from incoming calls, but failed to obtain it from outgoing ones.

I looked at tutorials and all of them suggest that I check the intent action and then get the number which I am trying to call.

in the manifest file I have added permissions and receiver

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in PhoneStateReceiver I'm trying to obtain phone numbers

```
 class PhoneStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    private val TAG = "PhoneStateReceiver"

    private var lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        checkCall(intent)
    }

    private fun checkCall(intent: Intent?) {
        val state = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

        if (intent?.action.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            var number = intent?.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)
            Log.d(TAG, "Outgoing number : $number")
        }else {
            if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    val number = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                    Log.d(TAG, "Incoming number : $number")
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, state)
        lastState = intState(state)
    }
```

and in MainActivity I'm only asking for permissions:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var PERMISSION_ALL = 1
    private var PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if(!hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
    }

    private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean = permissions.all {
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }


}
```

The action when making an outgoing call should be Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL 
However, when I make an outgoing call this action appears to be Intent.PHONE_STATE

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Add both actions into one `intent-filter`

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```